# ignore any non-alphabetic characters and capital letters from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

prob a silly question but here goes:

I am looking to ignore any non-alphabetic characters and also capital letters from a string.

```
        if (names[j].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
            System.out.println(names[j] + ":");
        }
```

I had something like that to test if there was a non-alphabetic character given and it works, just not sure on how to ignore them as such.

Any suggestions would be brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean ignore? take them out of the string or not do the condition if they are present?

Comment: I mean ignore in such that if NAtalie7@ was entered then natalie would be considered? I thought taking them out and changing the string to all lower case would be the best method but was wondering if it is possible to ignore them without removal. The code above was a quick test to check if the input wasnt all letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exapnding on @Jeff Storey's answer:

You do a replace on the regex `[^a-zA-Z]+` with the Empty String
If you really don't want to ignore the upper cases

After the replacement you convert the String into lower case

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String hello = "NAtalie7@";
    hello = hello.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(hello);
}
```

Will output:

```
natalie
```

If you want to ignore the first character regardless of what it is then you can use:

```
String hello = "NAtalie7@";
String ignoreFirstChar = hello.charAt(0) + (hello.substring(1,hello.length()).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").toLowerCase());
System.out.println(ignoreFirstChar);
```

Will output:

```
Natalie
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was after, I had thought that was the best option but wanted to double check. Apologies for the silly question :)

Comment: Sorry quick question, is there a way to skip the first character? So only do the replace after the first character regardless whether it needs replaced or not?

Comment: Sure.. let me test it and I get you the answer

Comment: Thank you, have played about with it and tried to break it up into characters and then started from index 1, however then I cannot use the replaceAll function.

Comment: hello = hello.charAt(0) + (hello.substring(1,hello.length()).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "").toLowerCase());

Comment: You have been a great help. These regular expressions are a brilliant tool just difficult to get the hang of :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45295/discussion-between-natalie-carr-and-gtgaxiola)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore them and strip them out, just use a regex to match them and replace them with an empty string. [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can take a regex.

Comment: I think they don't want upper case either, so would it be `names[j].replaceAll("[a-z]+","");` instead?

Comment: @ansible I read the opposite I was replacing the alphabet characters instead of the other way around

Comment: Sorry, I want to ignore anything non-alphabetic but if it is uppercase i want to keep it but it is not significant when matching with other words e.g Natalie will equal natalie