# Ignore line if any non-matching character is present

Tags: regex, bash, awk, inversion

I'm trying to print lines from a file if, and *only* if, every character in a line meets a certain regex condition.

The problem is that any line that contains any character that meets the regex condition evaluates to true and gets printed, even if it *also* contains characters outside that range.

I'd prefer to use `awk` as I already have additional conditions in place that I would like the evaluated line to meet, and would prefer the solution to implement basic regex so I can apply different matching conditions on future files (whereas the `grep` solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001177/how-do-i-grep-for-all-non-ascii-characters/) focuses on non-ASCII identification and seems to require `--perl-regexp` compatibility -- my focus is on meeting a given regex condition across an entire given line).

In the example, uppercase letters fall outside the regex condition and therefore the whole line where they appear should be ignored.

```
file.txt:
abc123
123abc
123ABC
AbCdEf
```

When I try...

```
awk '$0 ~ /[a-z]/ || $0 ~ /[0-9]/' < file.txt
```

...every line is printed, since the regex condition is met at least once in each line:

```
abc123
123abc
123ABC
AbCdEf
```

What I want is to **not** print a line if any character outside the `[a-z]` and/or `[0-9]`range is present, so the desired output here would be:

```
abc123
123abc
```

The closest hits I could find when researching this are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665549/have-sed-ignore-non-matching-lines/1665574#1665574) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139843/ignore-any-non-alphabetic-characters-and-capital-letters-from-a-string), but I don't want to search-and-replace anything on the line, I just want to ignore the line and move on to the next one if any unwanted characters are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given sample input/output, try these:

```bash
$ awk '!/[^a-z0-9]/' ip.txt
abc123
123abc

$ grep -v '[^a-z0-9]' ip.txt
abc123
123abc
```

- `[^set]` means match any character *except* `s` or `e` or `t` - in other words, `^` at the beginning of the class inverts the characters to be matched
- `!` and `-v` are used to print lines that do not match the given condition

The above solutions will match empty lines as well. To avoid that, you can use:

```bash
awk '/^[a-z0-9]+$/' ip.txt
grep -xE '[a-z0-9]+' ip.txt
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!
For my real-world example (only lines that contain chars from [space] to ~) I can use `awk '!/[^ -~]/'`
Could you characterize what job the `!` and `^` are doing that accomplish the goal? I thought `^` means "match any character except" .. so does the `!` turn it into a double-negative (inversion)?

Comment: Yeah, I think you got that right. `/[^a-z0-9]/` will match a line if it contains other than lowercase alphabets or digits, for example `A` or `;` or space, etc. But such lines should not be part of the output, so `!` and `-v` are used to invert the condition.